# Baking flour and sour cream -US /UK terms

Tags: baking, flour, cream

What is the UK equivalent of US 'baking flour' and does the term 'sour cream' describe the same product in both countries?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "baking flour" in the US - could it be "cake flour"?

Answer (score 4):

Typically referred to as "soured cream" in the UK, it is the same as "sour cream" in the US.

While there are many different types of flour, Baking flour is the same in the UK as it is in the US.